# Resolver operação com Conjunto

Tags: c, c++, matemática

> Questão 1 - Considere o conjunto X = {x ∈ Z : 1 ≤ x ≤ 32}. Implemente um programa em C, que execute as seguintes instruções.
>
> 1. Crie três vetores do tipo inteiro de tamanho 12: vetor0[12], vetor1[12] e vetor2[12].
> 2. Armazene no vetor0 os elementos pertecentes a X que deixam resto 0 quando divididos por 3.
> 3. Armazene no vetor1 os elementos pertecentes a X que deixam resto 1 quando divididos por 3.
> 4. Armazene no vetor2 os elementos pertecentes a X que deixam resto 2 quando divididos por 3.
> 5. Imprima os elementos contidos no vetor0.
> 6. Imprima os elementos contidos no vetor1.
> 7. Imprima os elementos contidos no vetor2.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse código?

Hoje pela tarde um amigo me pediu ajuda para resolver uma questão na faculdade.
Gosto muito de programar, contudo já tem muitos anos que terminei o ensino médio e não lembro mais como se resolve conjuntos. A única coisa que lembro é de meu professor escrever vetores na lousa ou desenhar bolinhas para analisar se existia interseção entre dois ou mais conjuntos.

Comment: O conjunto X representa os números inteiros entre 1 e 32, inclusive, então basta declarar e inicializar cada vetor com os respectivos valores.  O exercício não pede para fazer isso dinamicamente, então pode analisar na mão (não há operações entre conjuntos no exercício). Depois basta fazer três laços de repetição e exibir os valores dos vetores.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Isso tá com cara de falha no enunciado por parte do professor. Que talvez não dê o braço a torcer se alguém chegar com uma resposta como a que você sugere.

Comment: Guilherme, no entanto, aqui no site esse tipo de pergunta é considerada muito ampla. Pedidos de código a partir de um enunciado somente costumam ser mal vistos. Sugiro que você edite a pergunta e inclua uma tentativa de resolver sozinho.

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto, realmente achei um pouco imprudente a pergunta. Pela razão do meu problema se tratar de não saber resolver o problema matemático. Mas muito obrigado pela dica, e pela solução do problema. Obrigado.

Comment: Entendeu que a chave é o operador de módulo `%`? Mas atenção que a resposta que te deram tem um problema, ela considera um conjunto de 33 itens (0 a 32) em vez de 32 (1 a 32).

Comment: Entende perfeitamente, já havia usado o operador anteriormente. E muito bem observado de fato o for inicia em 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Crie três vetores do tipo inteiro de tamanho 12: vetor0[12],
>   vetor1[12] e vetor2[12].

```
int i, vet0 = 0, vet1 = 0, vet2 = 0;
int vetor0[12], vetor1[12], vetor2[12];

for(i = 1; i <= 32; i++){
    // Para calcular o resto, usamos %.
        if((i % 3) == 0){
            vetor0[vet0] = i;
            vet0++;
        }
        if((i % 3) == 1){
            vetor1[vet1] = i;
            vet1++;
        }
        if((i % 3) == 2){
            vetor2[vet2] = i;
            vet2++;
        }
    }
}
```

Para imprimir tudo, use:

```
int n;
for(n = 0; n < 12; n++){
    printf("%d ", vetor0[n]);
}
printf("\n");
for(n = 0; n < 12; n++){
    printf("%d ", vetor1[n]);
}
printf("\n");
for(n = 0; n < 12; n++){
    printf("%d ", vetor2[n]);
}
```

Comment: Desculpe, havia um erro no codigo, tente novamente agora.

Comment: Agora funciona, a unica coisa que faltou foi adicionar uma condicional para o caso de ter menos elementos que o tamanho do vetor, ou mais elementos. Mas a estrutura em si é essa, desculpe o erro.

Comment: Não há nada errado em errar; ele existe para podermos aprender. O importante é que corrigiu o erro. Outra coisa é que você pode iniciar os vetores com `{0}`, fazendo `vetor1[12] = {0}`, para evitar lixos de memória. E seria interessante explicar com palavras a solução, pois aquilo que pode ser trivial para nós pode não ser para todos os usuários.